# Is there any upside in using Bluetooth tethering instead of wifi tethering when using Android devices?

Tags: internet, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I use Internet on my S23 Ultra phone via Bluetooth tethering. Is there any upside in using Bluetooth tethering instead of wifi tethering when using Android devices?

Comment: In general Bluetooth is slower than Wifi. There are some very fast Bluetooth connection types that incorporates Wifi technology into the Bluetooth connection. But I am not sure if those modes are available in reality and not only in the specification papers.